# Error Messages are not displayed on my custom registration form phtml page in magento

Tags: magento

I am currently working on managing three types(normal user, Author, Editor) of users in magento.

I need to create a separate registration forms for Author and editor. But all the users are saved using the single `createpost action` in `Accountcontroller.php` .

The registration form for author is in authorregister.phtml every thing is working fine except the error messages.

Form error messages are not diplayed on the authorregister.phtml file. 
Then i plced the block `$this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml();` even after that also the error messages are not displyed.

To My Surprise these error messages are going and displaying on `persistent/customer/form/register.phtml` page.

i am unable to find the issue why this form error messages are getting displayed on that page load.

can any one help me out.

Comment: check if there are any JS errors.

Comment: Please provide your controller action in your question. I wonder if you are not initializing the messages properly? `$this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');`

Answer (score 0):

Hello following tips may be help you.....

In `authorregister.phtml` add first line

```
< div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>< /div>

 In Accountcontroller.php before redirect 
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Thank you .'));
```